# nginx configure Front and Backend

Tags: html, nginx, webserver

I have a backend running at `localhost:8080`. And the path `/runFuction` executes a certain command.

Now I would like to use nginx as web server for my front end and only sent certain request to my backend.

My nginx config looks as follows

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   <path to site>;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
    location /api {
     proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
    }
}
```

In my `index.html` site I have a form that

```
...
 <form action="api/runFuction" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
....
    <input type="submit" value="Do" />
</form>
```

I assumed that this would be possible but somehow I am missing something. How can I reach the backend path since I alway get a `404 page not there`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try it?

```
location /api/ {
    rewrite ^/api^/ /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. why is it always these small mistakes. I guess it is the regular expression that corrects it.